# UIImageView setImage does not work for IBOutlet

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, interface-builder, iboutlet

I want to set an image as my background at runtime, so I created a `UIImageView` 'backGroundImage' as `IBOutlet` in Interface Builder. However the following code:

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    NSLog(@"image=nil %d",(image ==nil));
    NSLog(imageName);
    [self.backGroundImage setImage:image];
    NSLog(@"backgroundImage=nil %d",(self.backGroundImage.image ==nil));
```

gives me the following `NSLogs`

```
2012-06-15 12:09:43.967 iElster[1960:207] image=nil 0

2012-06-15 12:09:43.967 iElster[1960:207] bedroom-sketch-corel-eps-vector-art-1141.jpg

2012-06-15 12:09:43.968 iElster[1960:207] backgroundImage=nil 1
```

so basically I can load my image, but I can not set it as the image of the `UIImageView`. If I  include the following line

```
backGroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
```

I don't get 'nil' anymore for my `backGroundImage.image` -  but in that case I obviously don't use the `UIImageView` created by the Outlet anymore. I do not see the problem with my code above, especially since all I saw as suggestions in similar Stack Overflow threads was exactly the same: "simply use the setImage method"; Any ideas what could be the problem?

**PS:** just to clarify that - I tried using different images, both .png and .jpg and they all work if I e.g. just set them as a subview to my `ScrollView`, but not when trying to use them in the code above. So the image files shouldn't pose any problems.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to 'connect' the UIImageView from the IB to IBOutlet in your code. Is that the case?

Comment: I have it properly @synthesized and I did connect the UIImageView to the IBOutlet by ctrl+dragging in IB (I actually double checked both things several times way before posting here)

Comment: Try to put in the following line: `NSLog (@"self.backGroundImage is nil: %@", self.backgroundImage?@"NO":@"YES");` and ditch that `backGroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];` - it shouldn´t be there. One more thing: **in which method do you have this code?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you placed this code in a method that is executed *before* the view gets loaded and the outlets are connected (e.g., in `init...`). Try placing it in `viewDidLoad`. You cannot access your view outlets before the view gets loaded (i.e., before `viewDidLoad` is accessed).

Also, this line:

```
[image release];
```

is a memory management error (overrelease).

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I had it indeed placed in the init.. method, because i was giving the "imageName" string as an argument and was to lazy to create a NSString property in my class to store that information.